# Use Combo-Box in MS Access to switch between different back-end databases?

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

I'm currently working on an MS Access application. It is a split database application which is designed to have one front-end and multiple backend databases, which are identical in structure and contained tables and queries. I tried to have all the data contained in one database, but I didn't have enough common identifiers that would let me clearly separate the data.

As I already have a main user interface in the front-end part anyway, my current idea is that I want a combo-box which lets me choose which project the data should come from (i.e which backend database). Is there a way to implement such a functionality with VBA code? I really don't want all the data stored in one continuous list, so this would be my preferred option.

Thanks for your tips and hints in advance. BR, Michael

Comment: Rethink your database schema. You should have a `Project` table with a `ProjectID`. Then project dependent tables would have a `ProjectID`  as foreign key (at least at the top level of table hierarchies) that you can use to filter the data. This will make project switches much easier. Otherwise, select a back-end at startup and relink all the tables.

Comment: If you have identifier for switching backends then you have identifier for filtering.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @OlivierJacot-Descombes, I thought of that as well. But my issue with that is, that for each project numerous csv-files need to be imported into the tables of the database. If one of those contained an error and needed to be re-imported, I could simply delete all the data from the table and re-import the new file. I'm a bit worried, that with a shared database I might run into a lot of issues, especially since the data must not be mixed. For context, the csv-files contain addresses with different additional informations. But I'll think about your suggestion a bit more.Thx

Comment: Thanks @June7, that's definitely helpful!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.